# How do I update the user email addresses once I made a change in the Google Directory API?

Tags: python, list, api, google-api, google-directory-api

I am trying to change the email addresses of all the users appearing in the Google Admin Directory of the organization with the use of the Google Directory API. I am struggling however, to commit the updates to the database once I made the changes.

I have managed to print out all the users, and change their email addresses, then print it again and see that the change worked. However this was only done locally, whilst I am trying to make the update applied to the actual user accounts. So once I have changed the email addresses how do I actually update with the API? The code posted is from the Google Python quickstart with a minor change

```
# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
print('Getting the first 10 users in the domain')
results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
                            orderBy='email').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])
user['email']['secondaryEmail'] = user['email']['customSchema']
#HOW DO I APPLY THIS CHANGE ON THE ACTUAL USER PROFILES NOW?

if not users:
    print('No users in the domain.')
else:
    print('Users:')
    for user in users:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'],
            user['name']['fullName']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You rename users with the [directory.users.update method here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update).  In python it looks like this:

```
response = results = service.users().update(
    userKey='existing_email_address',
    body={
        'primaryEmail': 'newEmailAddress@domain.com'
    }
).execute()
print(response)
```